# Eclipse Emulator not responding

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I run my android app on the eclipse emulator. I get

```
"Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched..."
```

in the console and just a black screen (not even the android logo) in the emulator. I have been waiting for a long time, but there is no response from the emulator.

I need to test in this emulator only, because I have created a new emulator device with configuration as that of - `"Motorola - Droid Turbo"`.

I don't know why this eclipse emulator is not working; Can anyone help me on this please??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does any other emulator run?

Comment: No. not even one emulator runs, I am using Windows8 Eclipse Kepler....I dunno what the problem is

Comment: Maybe you are using an old computer with a slow CPU, low RAM and integrated GPU? Consider using a less resurce consuming OS, such as Windows XP or Linux.

Comment: @DerGolem I have already tried using Linux...I get the same problem :(

Comment: Upgrade your computer, then. Suggested hardware: nVidia GPU, i7 CPU, minimum 8 GB RAM DDR3/1600, minimum CPU speed 2.2GHz (all cores unparked), SSD hard disk(s)...

Comment: @BharatMurali are you using intel processor?

Answer (score 3):

I would rather comment but I can't, If you are running System Image API 19 or higher in AVD it would take a lot of time to load or may not load at all. try System image API 18 or low and see if your emulator works, kindly show an screen shot of your AVD when you were creating it, a lot of information can be gathered from that.

Comment: I'm using only API 9 :(

Comment: would you mind showing the screen while you create AVD, make sure you click on Use Host GPU

Answer (score 2):

Yes, API 19 or higher system images do take more time to load.
If you want an immediate response, try it on a real android device.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Genymotion emulator. It much faster than standart emulator.

Comment: @mlK Is there any open-source emulator like Genymotion?

Comment: @prashanth-sams i heard only about standart emulator and Genymotion.

Comment: @PrashanthSams why do you ask for open-source? Genymotion is free and this should be sufficient anyone I guess.

Comment: @Sufian Genymotion is free for non-commercial use. https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc

Comment: @mIK thanks for correction. Using for commercial purposes didn't cross my mind.