# Emulator is starting and running slowly for android application using elicpse

Tags: android, performance

I am using Eclipse new v22.6.2 . My emulator is starting and running very slowly... How to overcomes this problem..using 3.7"WQVGA(240x432:IDPI).
system configuration is 2GB RAM and 64 bit windows 8 and i3 processor

Comment: at least 4 gb ram is recommended

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972166/android-eclipse-emulator-not-responding/26972388#26972388,  and yes Genymotion is a good option

Comment: I have 8 GB RAM, i7 8 Core Processor but Emulator still works slowly. Best solution is Genymotion for me. Starts in 5-15 seconds. Works much faster than real phone.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/). It is free for personal use.

Just had this issue myself (even though I believe to have a nice piece of hardware) and found that it's really faster as it claims to be.

In my notebook, it will get up and running in about 20-30 secs. Hope that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Increase eclipse Memory size since you emulator is using its memory to run. [See here to give more memory.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Genymotion is the better option if you want to test your app with emulator.

In my personal opinion it is always best to test app with the real devices.